# no [query] registered for [query] in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm struggling with an elasticsearch query for version 7.6

my query is like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "segmentations.catalog",
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "match": {
                              "segmentations.catalog.hash": "ad2626251c63fb7650e73e4f3d01d1fd"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

my mapping schema is the following

[image]

I'm getting always the same error no [query] registered for [query]

Thanks inadvance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one too many `query`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {                                     <---- remove query from here
                "nested": {
                  "path": "segmentations.catalog",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "segmentations.catalog.hash": "ad2626251c63fb7650e73e4f3d01d1fd"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```